# How do I incorporate async queues within dask/streamz tasks?

Tags: python, dask

I have multiple tasks that execute in sequence. I want to handle errors without breaking the processing. I am ok with a result that skips the errors as long as I can look at the errors later or even better push them back into the processing after some data correction.

I tried using dask and was able to create a process that executes, but I had to use dask.submit which needs the function name. I tried streamz and I was able to get to the following solution.

```py
import json
from streamz import Stream
from dask.distributed import Client

def save_error(data):
    with open("data/error.json", "a+") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data)+"\n")

def step1(data):
    if isinstance(data["x"], int):
        data["x"] *= 10
        return data

    logger.emit({"error":"invalid input","step":"step1", "data":data})
    return None

 def step2(data):

    try:
        data["x"] /= data["y"]
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        logger.emit({"error":e.args,"step":"step2", "data":data})
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":

     client = Client()

     main = Stream()
     logger = Stream(asynchronous=True)
     data = [
       {"x":1, "y": 4},
       {"x":2, "y": 3},
       {"x":"x", "y": 2},
       {"x":"y", "y": 6},
       {"x":7, "y": 0},
       {"x":8, "y": 2}
     ]

     logger.sink(save_error)
     main.map(step1) \
         .filter(lambda x: x != None) \
         .map(step2) \
         .filter(lambda x: x != None) \
         .sink(print)


     for item in data:
         main.emit(item)

     client.close()
```

In the original example https://streamz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dask.html, a simple number list is used and switching from local execution to `dask` distributed execution is possible by just adding scatter, buffer and gather.

However, if I use a `dict` instead of number, using scatter and gather gives incorrect results.

Without scatter, buffer and gather

```py
def inc(data):
    data["x"] = data["x"] + 1
    return data

source = Stream()

x = (source.map(inc)
           .sink(print))

for i in range(5):
    source.emit({"x": i*4, "y": i % 5})
```

Output:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 0}
{'x': 5, 'y': 1}
{'x': 9, 'y': 2}
{'x': 13, 'y': 3}
{'x': 17, 'y': 4}
```

With scatter, buffer and gather

```py
def inc(data):
    data["x"] = data["x"] + 1
    return data

client = Client()
source = Stream()

x = (source.scatter()
           .map(inc)
           .buffer(8)
           .gather()
           .sink(print))

for i in range(5):
    source.emit({"x": i*4, "y": i % 5})
```

Output:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 0}
{'x': 1, 'y': 0}
{'x': 1, 'y': 0}
{'x': 1, 'y': 0}
{'x': 1, 'y': 0}
```

I can use a separate asynchronous stream to push the error log like in the code above, but it cannot be used with scatter and gather.

I don't understand why the scatter/gather result is different for json where it works perfectly with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Streamz doesn't use Dask by default.  You may want to look here: https://streamz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dask.html

I you don't want to use streamz you might also want to look at Dask Futures and [as_completed](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.as_completed)

Comment: Thanks, I had started with the streamz example you have mentioned here. The problem I faced was that if I change the input from a simple number to a json like below  

```python 
def inc(data):
    data["x"] += 1
   return data
for i in range(20):
        source.emit({"x": i*4, "y": i % 5}) 
```

I get the output as always {"x":1, "y": 0} .

Answer (score 0):

I found that [prefect](https://www.prefect.io/) allows me to skip rows/items that have issues and it also allows me to use `dask` for parallel execution.

It may be possible to make the custom LogHandler to be asynchronous.

Since this code worked with `dask executer`, it should be possible to achieve the skipping of error plus handling errors without impacting the primary processing pipeline with plain `dask` as well.

```py
import logging
import requests
import prefect
from prefect import task, Flow, engine
from time import sleep
from prefect.utilities.logging import get_logger
import json

class LogHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        requests.post("http://0.0.0.0:3000/", json=record.msg)

@task
def inc(data):
    logger = prefect.context.get("logger")
    if (data["x"] %7 != 0):
        data["x"] += 1
        return data
    else:
        logger.error({"error": "simulated error", "data":data, "step":"inc"})
        raise engine.signals.SKIP("Simulated error")

@task
def dec(data):
    logger = prefect.context.get("logger")
    if (data != None):
        data["y"] -= 1
        logger.info({"data":data, "step":"dec"})
        return data

@task
def add(x, y):
    logger = prefect.context.get("logger")
    res = x["x"] + y["y"]
    logger.info({"res": res})
    return res

@task(name="show", skip_on_upstream_skip=False)
def show_result(data, res):
    logger = prefect.context.get("logger")
    success= [item for item in res if not isinstance(item, engine.result.NoResultType)]
    logger.info({"data":data, "result": success})

def main():
    data = [{"x": x, "y": x % 5, "z": x % 3} for x in range(10)]

    with Flow("dask-example") as flow:
        incs = inc.map(data)
        decs = dec.map(incs)
        adds = add.map(x=incs, y=decs)

        show_result(data, decs)

    task_logger = get_logger("Task")
    task_logger.addHandler(LogHandler())

    flow.run() # runs this flow on its schedule

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```